# JavaScript function calling with time interval

Tags: javascript

How call JavaScript functions in time interval. I want call a function with time interval how can I done that

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+interval

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call it after a certain time interval you can do something like this (this will do it after 3 seconds);

```
setInterval(MyFunc, 3000);
```

`setInterval()` has a signature that is a function being the first parameter and the interval in milliseconds as the second parameter (thus the amount of seconds is equal to 3000/1000 as there are 1000 milliseconds per second).  SetInterval will also call that function over and over again every 3 seconds!  So make sure you want it to!

For example if you wanted to show an alert you could do:

```
setInterval(function() { alert("Hello World") }, 3000);
```

If you want it to run only once just replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` which will just run it once after the time given (again in milliseconds).